# iTunes shortcut to delete files from disk

Tags: itunes, shortcut

I remember iTunes has a shortcut "Cmd + Opt + delete" to delele files from disk, it works in any playlist in iTunes. But now it's no longer available.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can't repro, 10.11.1 & iTunes 12.3.1.23 Works with delete or backspace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, after iCloud Music Upgrade, `Opt + Delete` gives 2 options now,

1. Delete locally
2. Delete from iCloud Music Library

[image]

You can remove local copy from Edit Menu though

[image]

You can add a Keyboard Shortcut for this form `Keyboard Shortcuts` `System Preferences`

Make sure the iTunes Media Folder is set up correctly for you.

[image]

Comment: Sorry but Opt + Delete doesn't work. The .mp3 file is still in my hard disk. I download MP3s from other sources and put it locally.

Comment: @Matt, have you enabled "Copy files to iTunes Media folder...` in iTunes' preferences? It deletes the file only from the Media Library.

Comment: It doesn't delete files that you play from say Downloads folder

Comment: Arrrg, thank you, not exactly as your instruction, I change the path to my external disk (where I saved all my MP3 files), and now the shortcut works like a charm.

Comment: @Matt, awesome, glad you could get it working :)

Comment: Is this still supposed to work? "Delete" now seems to be under Song > "Delete from Library" instead, and there's no keyboard command attached to it by default. Furthermore, I don't have a proper Delete key on my MacBook Pro.